# Java outer and inner classes have method with the same name: non-static method static context error

Tags: java, oop

I have public class A and inner class B. A and B have a method with the same name `change` but with different signatures and return types. To call A's method `change` from B's `change` I need to print `A.this.change(i, w)`.

Why? Why can't I print just `A.change(i, w)`? Wouldn't it be enough to resolve the name conflict issue? If I leave `A.change(i, w)` instead of `A.this.change(i, w)` it gives me a `Non-static method 'change(int, java.lang.String)` cannot be referenced from a static context` error.

```
public class A  {
     private int x;
     private String y;

     A()  {
        x=5;
        y="Default";
     }

     A(int x, String y)  {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
     }

     int change(int n, Strin w)  {
        x+=n;
        y+=w;
        return x;
     }

     class B  {
          private int i;

          B()  {
             i=2;
          }

          void change(String w)  {
                A.this.change(i, w);
          }
    }
```

Comment: `A.change` would be a `static` call, with `A.this.change` you´re going back to executing it on an instance of this specific `A`

Comment: `A.change(...)` and on which instance? There can exist several of them.

Comment: @Kevin Esche Why would it be a static call if class `B` is non-static and neither of the two `change` method is static. It's a given there is some `A` class instance when one of the two `change` methods is executed.

Comment: @Tom How is that? If so, then why can I just ask for `x` or `y` variables from `B` if different instances can have different values stored there?

Comment: @parsecer whilst that is true the compiler pretty much notices `Classname.Methodname`, so it resolves to a `static` call. Implementing something like distinguishing between inner and outer calls in order to notify `static` calls would be unneccessary, and on another node this would be horrendous in terms of readabilty.

Comment: @Kevin Esche So compiler treats all methods inside an inner class as if those were `static`? But why I can access `x, y and i` then without making them static or using `this`?

Comment: `x` and `y` are instances _inside_ of `B`, but `A` isn't.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions including the comments:

1. `Classname.methodname` is the way you would call a `static` method, which `A#change(int, String)` doesn´t represent, so the compiler does notify you for this.
2. instance methods are executed within the current scope, which in case your `A.this.change` would be the scope of `B`. As `B` doesn´t have a method `change(int, String)` you need to guide java to the scope you´re trying to execute there, which is `A#change(int, String)`. To resolve this you´re writing `A.this.change(intVal, stringVal)`. The `A` tells java that the method you´re trying to execute will be part of the class `A`. The `this` is necessary to distinguish between `static` and `instance` calls.
3. Why can´t we still just write `A.change(intVal, stringVal`)?
   Well as `B` is defined as `not static` it will clearly be bound to the `A` instance, and the `this` feels kinda redundant right (The main part of the question)? But ask yourself, what would be the advantage of distinguishing `inner-` and `outer classes`? You could leave out the `this` yeah, but on the other side you´d be reducing the readability, because one would need to check if the inner class is `static` or not in order to notice if `A.change(intVal, stringVal)` would be executed in a `static` context or not. In the end this could be implemented but the upsides for this as just leaving the `.this` wont surpass the downside of needing to be more carefull when reading and writing inner classwa code. And as though i´d say every `Classname.methodname` should correctly be treated as a `static` call instead of implementing special case scenarios for specific cases here.

I hope this "answer" answers your question good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since the signature is different there is no conflict in naming. `public void x(String str){}` and `public void(int in){}` are considered different methods anyway. If you call `A.change()` you have to declare the change method static. Doing the  `A.this.change` is like:

```
A a= new A();
a.change();
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is `A.change(...)` calls a static method of class A and `A.this.change(...)` calls the method of an instance of class A.

Try this example:

```
public class A {
    public static void staticMethod() {
        System.out.println("-> A's static method");
    }
    public void nonStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("-> A's non static method");
    }
    class B {
        public void test() {
            A.staticMethod();
            A.this.nonStaticMethod();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A.B b = a.new B();
        b.test();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
-> A's static method
-> A's non static method
```

So `A.this` references the current instance of the outer class while `A` is just the outer class itself.